# How does method that remote controller exchange the sensor data with VR headset

Tags: android, wifi, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, google-vr

Hi I have recognized that controller send sensors data via BLE or WIFI, but I want to look where the sensor data are processed in Android N framework. Does anyone give me some directions to study? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I study this for two week, I think the sensor data are processed in google vr service. But the google vr service is not open source.